# Rx Android/Java: How to Sequentially combine two observable of different type

Tags: functional-programming, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-android

I want to check the status of user after particular time delay.

I have two `Observables:`

1. Timer Observable: Which emits event after particular delay.

   Observable timer = Observable.timer((endTime - startTime), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
2. `Observable` which gets the current status of user.

   Observable status = getCurrentStatusObservable(id);

I have to combine these observable sequentially and then result should emit.
For implementing this I used zip operator with following approach.

```
return Observable.zip(timer, status, new Func2<Long, CurrentStatus, CurrentStatus>() {
            @Override
            public Program call(Long aLong, CurrentStatus status) {
                return program;
            }
        });
```

But problem is that `status` `observable` is getting executed before `timer` blows. Hence `zip` operator is returning `status` which is old. But I want `status` `Observable` to execute after `timer` blows.

Please let me know if I am using wrong operator. I checked `concat` operator, but it need `Observable` of same type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just a regular `flatMap`

```
return timer.flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<CurrentStatus>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<CurrentStatus> call(Long aLong) {
        return status;
    }
});
```

Comment: I agree with your answer. I was trying to use zip operator for this, using flatMap is easy and correct approach. Is there be a way to do same work by using operator other than flatMap.